# What's the matter with this Grammar?

Tags: antlr, grammar

```
grammar Test;

IDHEAD: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_');
IDTAIL: (IDHEAD | '0'..'9');
ID:     (IDHEAD IDTAIL*);
fragment
TYPE:   ('text' | 'number' | 'bool');

define: 'define' ID 'as' TYPE;
```

The problem is that the `define` rule matches the tokens `define`, `ID`, `as`, but wont match `TYPE`.  I'm yielding a MissingTokenException.

If I inline the TYPE, as follows, it works as I'm intending:

```
grammar Test;

IDHEAD: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_');
IDTAIL: (IDHEAD | '0'..'9');
ID:     (IDHEAD IDTAIL*);
fragment
TYPE:   ('text' | 'number' | 'bool');

define: 'define' ID 'as' ('text' | 'number' | 'bool');
```

---

Update:  The `fragment` keyword was added in an effort to resolve another conflict: `The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: TYPE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the combined grammar, place your parser rules above your lexer rules. Also, remember that the lexer runs first and only after it's finished the parser runs. The `TYPE` (lexer) token must be matched before it's known that the `define` (parser) rule needs it.

Fragment lexer rules do not create tokens, but they can be composed into non-fragment rules that do create tokens. In your example, `IDHEAD` and `IDTAIL` are not tokens - they are just used to describe the parts of `ID`. As such, `TYPE` and `ID` are your non-fragment rules, and `IDHEAD` and `IDTAIL` are fragment rules.

```
grammar Test;

define: 'define' ID 'as' TYPE;

/*
 * Lexer rules only below here
 */

TYPE:   ('text' | 'number' | 'bool');
ID:     (IDHEAD IDTAIL*);

fragment
IDHEAD: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_');

fragment
IDTAIL: (IDHEAD | '0'..'9');
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought the lexer rules have a priority of how they are listed.  So if you want token TYPE to actually be created, move it above all the other lexer rules.

```
grammar Test;

fragment
TYPE:   ('text' | 'number' | 'bool');
IDHEAD: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_');
IDTAIL: (IDHEAD | '0'..'9');
ID:     (IDHEAD IDTAIL*);

define: 'define' ID 'as' TYPE;
```

Comment: formating was lost, but you can still see how the order of the lexer rules.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because TYPE is defined as fragment?

Can't test right now, but try and remove fragment, and that should do the trick, plus give you a token to boot.

Answer (score 0):

What is the line with `fragment` supposed to be doing? I think it should work as you expect if you remove it.